# Android 4.4 Cannot Display PDF (pdfname is of invalid format)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, pdf-viewer

I developed an app that downloads a pdf invoice from a local server and views it using the default pdf viewer. 
Initially started with smaller files (± 20 kB) and all works fine.

A new billing cycle has passed and there are new invoices with much bigger file size (± 900 kB), and now when I try to view them, Google pdf viewer, Google Drive PDF viewer give the TOAST error Cannot display PDF (factura.pdf is of invalid format)

I tried other pdf viewers, some open blank PDFs, some get stuck on a loading status screen.

The app downloads the PDF to external storage before viewing it, and the strange thing is if I try to open the PDF from external storage, it does open fine, just inside the app, it does not. So I know the file is not corrupted and downloads fine.

To view the document, I am not using anything out of the ordinary:

```
     public void view(View v)
{
    File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Facturas/" + "factura.PDF");
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    try{
        startActivity(pdfIntent);
    }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(BuscaFactura.this, "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Notes: All permissions in Manifest are set to read and write to and from external storage.

I tried lower case and upper case extensions as I read on some forum but that makes no difference.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First try to open that pdf in your coputer to verify that pdf is valid file.

Comment: Hello @ArbazAlam As mentioned, the pdf opens fine from the external storage on the android device, so the pdf is valid. Thank you

Comment: If you don't have any specific requirement, I can provide you all code to achieve your requirement in a different way.

Comment: @ArbazAlam I just want to be able to view the PDF. I have a print button configured to print the file downloaded into the external storage and that is working fine. I am looking into rendering the PDF locally or view it in a WebView. I would appreciate your solution as well.